# How to build & test a C linux program for many architectures without setting up environment for each one?

Tags: linux, architecture

Suppose I've written a simple program in C. It builds and runs successfully on my primary arch.

Now I want to find out on what architectures the program can be built and works; also provide pre-built executables for download for variety of platforms. However I have only few of them.

The most obvious way seems to be set up maximum number of cross compiling tool chains and maximum number of executable images for different architectures. But this seems to be inconvenient (especially if you just want it for one little program).

How to do it in a simple way? Should I use some on-line service which provides already set up for development systems for various architectures?

Expecting something like this:

```
user$ ssh i386.buildhere.example
guest@i386 $ echo 'int main(){}' > hello.c
guest@i386 $ gcc hello.c -o hello
guest@i386 $ ./hello
guest@i386 $ file hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 8038....
```

```
user$ ssh armel.buildhere.example
guest@armel $ ....
```

...

Additional bonus whould be if there are also various outdated systems availble to test "how my program would behave on that legacy distribution?".

Comment: Against what standards did you code your program? What is your program doing? What libraries do you use?

Comment: A C program relying mostly on glibc, buildable with `gcc source.c -o program` (maybe with a few `-lwhatever` things)

Comment: That does not tell us much. If you believe to code against some well defined standard (e.g. some version of POSIX), there are good chances that all implementations of that standard should work.

Comment: The program may be coded without thinking much about standards, just "work vs not_work"... And even with standards it can be helpful to build and run it on everything.  The question is not "how to write portable C programs", it is about "how to build&test program on archs easily".

Comment: What do you call an architecture? Is i386 an architecture? Is Linux on i386 an architecture?What happens if it runs on Linux on i386 but not on Windows 7 on i386 and not FreeBSD on i386 does it really support i386?

Comment: The only sure way is to test it on a given configuration. Otherwise you cannot make any guarantees

Answer (score 3):

There is one thing that is ALMOST certain in programming: Whatever you do to test something will probably work, but whatever you haven't tested will fail when you give it to a customer.

Use of virtual machines will help to some degree to avoid having to buy unusual hardware, as does things like QEMU.

Unless your program is either REALLY trivial, or you want to use your customers [1] as guinea-pigs, you are best off testing on every platform-type that you want to release for. If you don't, it WILL come back and bite you at some point.

If you don't, you run the risk of some of your customers gets an "unhappy experience". An unhappy customer tells ten people, a happy customer tells maybe one person.

If you wish to support architectures/stuff that you don't have access to, maybe just having a "help yourself" option of source-code is a better choice than downloadable binaries.

Of course, you can rent time/space on servers of various kinds - I looked into writing an iPhone app, and there are places that run Mac's as virtual machines on the net that you can rent for around US$ 15 per month, for example.

[1] Throughout this answer, by customer, I mean anyone that downloads your software, regardless of whether they actually give some money to anyone, they will have spent some effort to get your software on their machine. If it doesn't work, then they will be unhappy to some degree. How unhappy depends on a number of things, including how clear you made it that "this may not work" if you were to publish "untested" software.

Comment: I provide source code for my little programs on Github. But I also want in addition to provide binaries (for ones that too lazy to find all deps to build the code) and try my programs myself at least once on other archs.

Comment: `Of course, you can rent time/space on servers of various kinds` -> I'm looking something like this, but for free, covering maximum number of various configurations. Maybe somebody offers such a service to assist FOSS development.

Comment: `There is one thing that is ALMOST certain in programming:` -> This is why I want this in the first place. But I want it to be simple, without lengthy env setup (downloading big files, setting up toolchains, occupying much diskspace...). I.e. to put away setting up things but still play with my program on various systems. Maybe somebody have already set up N+1 environments and is OK to share his setup efforts with community...